# I have a doubt that I have stated below

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

[image]
I was able to solve this question using the equation of string wave. However, I tried for an alternative solution:
$$\tan\theta_A\gt \tan\theta_B \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\tan\theta_A}\lt\frac{1}{\tan\theta_B} \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{\tan\theta_A}>-\frac{1}{\tan\theta_B} $$So,$$ R_A>R_B \;$$Because $$Particle's \; Speed = -(Wave's \; Speed)*(Slope)$$

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE. Please us [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset equations and formulae.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

All particles in the wave undergo simple harmonic motion. Hence the point A which is closer to the x-axis has higher velocity as compared to B. As the wave speed is constant for both particles, we can conclude that $R_B>R_A$.

Comment: The figure shows that it's not a harmonic wave.

Comment: @mikestone do not go on diagram it is assumed that it is sinusoidal pulse